# Node.js - Extracting part of the URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node.js server i have a URL variable.

It is either in the form of "https://www.URL.com/USEFUL_PART/blabla", or "URL.com/USEFUL_PART/blabla".

From this, i want to extract only the 'USEFUL_PART' information.

How do i do that with Javascript?

I know there are two ways to do this, one with vanilla js and one with regular expressions.
I searched the web but i only found SO solutions to specific questions. Unfortunately, i coulnd't find a generic tutorial i could replicate or work out my solution.

Comment: This is extremely common in http framework routing, you could checkout express or hapi to see how they handle this :)

Comment: I am using Express

Comment: Did u tried req.params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js you can use "URL"
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

```
const myURL = new URL('https://example.org/abc/xyz?123');
console.log(myURL.pathname);
// Prints /abc/xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Express, you can specify the part of the URL you want as parameters, like so:

```
app.get('/:id/blabla', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params); // Will be { id: 'some ID from the URL']
});
```

See also:  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

Answer (score 2):

Hey if you are using express then you can do something like this

```
app.get('/users/:id/blabla',function(req, res, next){
   console.log(req.params.id);
 }
```

Another way is to use javascript replace and split function

```
str = str.replace("https://www.URL.com/", "");
str = str.split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to check whether the url starts with `http or https`, if not then manually add `http`, parse the url using the URL api, take the patname from parsed url, and get the desired part

```js
let urlExtractor = (url) =>{
  if(!/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)){
    url = "http://" + url
  }
  let parsed = new URL(url)
  return parsed.pathname.split('/')[1]
}

console.log(urlExtractor("https://www.URL.com/USEFUL_PART/blabla"))
console.log(urlExtractor("URL.com/USEFUL_PART/blabla"))
```

Comment: If it doesn't contain ('http' OR 'https') it will add 'http' OK. But what if it contains 'http'? Will this code put an 'https' before it?

Comment: @user1584421 no it will add only when the http or https is missing at start